# Как удалить определенное изображение на карте

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

На карту добавляется скажем 100 маркеров

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            icon: image,
                            map: map
                        });

                        gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Есть изображение,

```
       CustomCircle = function (center, radius, map) {
            this.bounds_ = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: center,
                radius: radius
            }).getBounds();
            this.map_ = map;
            this.div_ = null;
            this.setMap(map);
        };
        CustomCircle.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        CustomCircle.prototype.onAdd = function () {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.position = 'absolute';

            var circle = document.createElement('div');
            circle.className = 'circle'; //class with custom styling
            circle.style.width = '100%';
            circle.style.height = '100%';
            circle.style.position = 'absolute';
            div.appendChild(circle);

            this.div_ = div;
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
        };
        CustomCircle.prototype.draw = function () {
            var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
            var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
            var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
            var div = this.div_;
            div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
            div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
            div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
            div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
        };
        CustomCircle.prototype.onRemove = function () {
            this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
            this.div_ = null;
        };
```

которое добавляется к определенным маркерам, с добавлением проблем нету

```
    CustomCircles = new CustomCircle(center, radius, map);
    Circles.push(new CustomCircle(center, radius, map));
```

Как убрать одно, определенное изображение

```
     Circles[i].onRemove();
```

приводит к ошибке Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null